# Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.driver.DMSFactory TopLink 12c and Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: oracle, glassfish-3, toplink

I'm in a deployment issue for weeks now and I'm seeking for your help.

I'm trying to deploy a `J2E` web application built up with `JDeveloper 12.1.2`. I'm using `topLink` as `ORM`, `Glassfish 3.1.2` as `AS`, `JDK 7` and `Oracle 11g` as `DBMS`.

After deploying the `.EAR` file of my project, I'm having this exception when trying to go through my application

> **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.driver.DMSFactory**

I've added **ojdbc7dms.jar** in my project classpath, but still having the same exception. The same behaviour with **ojdbc7.jar**

This is my **session.xml** file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<sessions version="2.4.2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <session xsi:type="server-session">
    <name>default</name>
    <!--<server-platform xsi:type="weblogic-10-platform"/>-->
    <primary-project xsi:type="xml">META-INF/dbMap.xml</primary-project>
  </session>
</sessions>
```

Below the complete stacktrace of the exception

> [#|2016-09-09T17:04:15.823+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|oracle.adf.model.adapter.bean.BeanDCInvocationHandler|_ThreadID=47;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|InvocationTargetException
>   ->invoke(findAllAdminModuleByRef) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor185.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   oracle.adf.model.adapter.bean.BeanDCInvocationHandler.invoke(BeanDCInvocationHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.adapter.bean.BeanDCInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(BeanDCInvocationHandler.java:69)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.adapter.bean.BeanDCInvocationHandler.invoke(BeanDCInvocationHandler.java:139)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.adapter.bean.BeanDCInvokeMethodHandler.invoke(BeanDCInvokeMethodHandler.java:125)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.adapter.bean.UpdatableBeanDataControl.invokeOperation(UpdatableBeanDataControl.java:600)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.adapter.bean.JavaBeanDataControl.invokeOperation(JavaBeanDataControl.java:388)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.bean.DCBeanDataControl.invokeMethod(DCBeanDataControl.java:477)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.binding.DCInvokeMethod.callMethod(DCInvokeMethod.java:266)
>     at
>   oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.doIt(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:1658)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControl.invokeOperation(DCDataControl.java:2189)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.bean.DCBeanDataControl.invokeOperation(DCBeanDataControl.java:560)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.adapter.AdapterDCService.invokeOperation(AdapterDCService.java:309)
>     at
>   oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.invoke(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:751)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.executeEvent(PageLifecycleImpl.java:407)     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding._execute(FacesCtrlActionBinding.java:255)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding.execute(FacesCtrlActionBinding.java:213)
>     at org.devtools.RhTools.executeAction(RhTools.java:152)     at
>   beans.admin.Mb_cfgDashboard.cfgDashboardAfterPhase(Mb_cfgDashboard.java:39)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.notifyPhaseListeners(UIViewRoot.java:1050)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.notifyAfter(UIViewRoot.java:853)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeEnd(UIViewRoot.java:1005)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.component.AdfViewRoot.encodeAll(AdfViewRoot.java:102)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl$ChangeApplyingVDLWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:338)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:170)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.ResponseRenderManager.runRenderView(ResponseRenderManager.java:52)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1104)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:255)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:478)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFFilter.doFilter(ServletADFFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.ejb.EJBException    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.findAllAdminModuleByRef(Unknown Source)
>     ... 100 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class oracle.jdbc.driver.DMSFactory    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createDMSSensors(PhysicalConnection.java:4361)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:805)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:420)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:31)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:612)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)  at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:330)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:293)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connect(DatasourceAccessor.java:418)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.buildConnection(ConnectionPool.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.startUp(ConnectionPool.java:504)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.connect(ServerSession.java:484)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:633)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:363)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionFactory.getSharedSession(SessionFactory.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionFactory.getSharedSession(SessionFactory.java:127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionFactory.acquireSession(SessionFactory.java:167)
>     at
>   ejb.admin.adminSessionEJBBean.findAllAdminModuleByRef(adminSessionEJBBean.java:196)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor188.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor187.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
>     ... 102 more |#]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. As I'm using Jdeveloper 12c, I just added the **ojdbcdms6.jar** file in the **model** project library and classpath, in addition of this jar been added to the viewcontroller project library and classpath.

Comment: Please share .jar link